# Как программно заблокировать экран в Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv

Пожалуйста, не помечайте вопрос как дублированный! На моем TV урезанный android 8.0, где нет ни возможности включить отладку по usb, ни даже api администрирования, благодаря которому на смартфоне работает метод lockNow. Возможно ли создать приложение, которое, пользуясь специальными возможностями, сможет выключить экран? Уже пробовал [этот вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294917/android-java-turn-screen-off) с PowerManager, безрезультатно